# How to change this powershell script to uncheck "allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" for Wi-Fi in addition to Ethernet

Tags: powershell, wifi, power-management

I have this script and it works to turn uncheck the box for the Ethernet adapter but no matter how I futz around with it I can't get it to do the same thing for Wi-Fi.

```
$NICs = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter -filter "AdapterTypeID = '0' AND PhysicalAdapter = 'true' AND NOT Description LIKE '%wireless%' AND NOT Description LIKE '%virtual%' AND NOT Description LIKE '%WiFi%' AND NOT Description LIKE '%Bluetooth%'"
Foreach ($NIC in $NICs)
{
    $powerMgmt = Get-WmiObject MSPower_DeviceEnable -Namespace root\wmi | where {$_.InstanceName -match [regex]::Escape($nic.PNPDeviceID)}
    If ($powerMgmt.Enable -eq $True)
    {
         $powerMgmt.Enable = $False
         $powerMgmt.psbase.Put()
    }
}
```

Have tried removing all the AND NOT lines.
Have tried a few other scripts I found online but to no avail.

```
$NICs = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter -filter "AdapterTypeID = '0' AND PhysicalAdapter = 'true' AND NOT Description LIKE '%wireless%' AND NOT Description LIKE '%virtual%' AND NOT Description LIKE '%WiFi%' AND NOT Description LIKE '%Bluetooth%'"
Foreach ($NIC in $NICs)
{
    $powerMgmt = Get-WmiObject MSPower_DeviceEnable -Namespace root\wmi | where {$_.InstanceName -match [regex]::Escape($nic.PNPDeviceID)}
    If ($powerMgmt.Enable -eq $True)
    {
         $powerMgmt.Enable = $False
         $powerMgmt.psbase.Put()
    }
}
```

I would want to to uncheck the "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" box under power management for the Wi-fi adapter under Network Connections.

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) Try to use the formatting tools the editor offers - your posts will look way better.

Comment: Have you tried just removing the `NOT`'s in your wmi query? Also, your second script snippet looks identical to the first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Powershell cmdlet `Get-NetAdapter` to identify your WLAN interfaces.
To do that you can use the property PhysicalMediaType.

In this case you want to search for WLAN adapters, so match it with `'Native 802.11'`.
For older operating systems sometimes we have to match it with `'Wireless LAN'`.

To get all WLAN Adapter u can use this in your Script:

```
$NICs = Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.PhysicalMediaType -eq 'Native 802.11' -or $_.PhysicalMediaType -eq 'Wireless LAN'}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows server 2016, you can edit GPO under: *Computer Configuration/ Policies/ Administrative Template / System /Power Management / Sleep Settings :* Allow network connectivity during connected-standby.

You can try to enable this settings and see if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$NICs = Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.status -eq 'Up'}

Foreach ($NIC in $NICs)
{
    $powerMgmt = Get-WmiObject MSPower_DeviceEnable -Namespace root\wmi | where {$_.InstanceName -match [regex]::Escape($nic.PNPDeviceID)}
    If ($powerMgmt.Enable -eq $True)
    {
         $powerMgmt.Enable = $False
         $powerMgmt.psbase.Put()
    }
}
```